# Delete rows within range according to values in a column

Tags: excel, delete-row, vba

I need to create a macro that would look at every cells only in a specific column (i.e. not the whole spreadsheet) and starting at a specific row. Then, it would have all rows that does not contain my value of interests.

Lets say for example my goal is to search every value in column "A" and I'll filter from A2 to A99999999, leaving A1 untouched.I would then delete every row that does not contain 103526 and 103527 in column A.

The following code is able to filter through all the rows for my values of interest, however, I am having trouble filtering only ONE column and from A2 to A99999999. How can I change this code to meet those conditions?

```
Sub test()    
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer    
Dim r As Range, cfind6 As Range, cfind7 As Range    
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate    
On Error Resume Next    
j = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    
For k = j To 1 Step -1    
Set cfind6 = Rows(k).Cells.Find(what:=103526, lookat:=xlWhole)    

Set cfind7 = Rows(k).Cells.Find(what:=103527, lookat:=xlWhole)    
If cfind6 Is Nothing And cfind7 Is Nothing Then Rows(k).Delete    

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to approach this, one way would be to change your code to something like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Not (ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = 103526 Or ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = 103527) Then
            ws.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```